# when click on the textbox inside the div, div onclick java script function fire

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a text box in side a div and i have use onclick java script function to change the color when i click on the div. but the problem is why that onclick function fire when i click on the text box also? is there any solution to prevent this java script function fire?

```
<table>
        @{int i=0;}
        @foreach (var m in Model.JobPostSundayTimeSlotVMList)
        {
           var divId = "SunSlot" + i;
           var checkboxId = "SunIsSelected" + i;
           var bitRate = "SunRate" + i;
           <tr>
               <td>
                   @Html.CheckBox("[" + i + "].SunIsSelected", m.SunIsSelected, new { @id = checkboxId, @hidden = "hidden" })

                    <div id="@divId" onclick = "setSlotColor('@divId','@checkboxId')";>  
                             @Html.TextBox("[" + i + "].SunParttimerBidValue", "", new { @id = bitRate, @class = "form-control", @placeholder = m.SunParttimerBidValue.ToString("C2"), @style = "height:20px"}) 
                    </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            i++;
      }
</table>
<script>
       function setSlotColor(divId, checkbox) {
       var property = document.getElementById(divId);
       if ($('#' + checkbox).prop('checked')) {
       $('#' + checkbox).prop('checked', false); 
       property.style.backgroundColor = "white"; 
       }
       else
       {
          property.style.backgroundColor = "burlywood";
          $('#' + checkbox).prop('checked', true);
        }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

Include the below code in your script. It will exclude the textboxes into the div from `onClick` event

If you'd replace the `div` selector with the div id or div css class name that will be more specific.

```
$("div input[type='text']").click(function () {
     e.stopPropagation()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the event to the method and then try doing `event.stopPropagation();` - this should stop the event from bubbling up to the other elements.

Interesting read - https://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing